# Why are some symbols recognized by Mathematica but nowhere in the documentation?

Tags: undocumented, symbols, groebner-bases

I was trying to calculate a Groebner basis for a given set of polynomials, and I did it successfully.  But I wanted to calculate the conversion matrix between the original basis and the Groebner basis.  Apparently Mathematica is able to do that with `` GroebnerBasis`BasisAndConversionMatrix `` in place of `GroebnerBasis`.

First, what does the `` ` `` mean?  Searching in the documentation only gives me things about precision.  Is `BasisAndConversionMatrix` a sub-function of `GroebnerBasis`?

Second, why is there a symbol that is unrecognized by Mathematica (it's blue when you type it), appears nowhere in the documentation, and yet appears to correctly do an important job?  Where am I supposed to have officially learned about this symbol?  Is it an official part of Mathematica, or is it a part of some unofficial package I've downloaded?

Comment: "Is `BasisAndConversionMatrix` a sub-function of `GroebnerBasis`?" - pretty much. A lot of explicitly available functions in *Mathematica* are implemented using undocumented low-level or utility functions, that are usually not intended for users. That being said, if you look at the [tag:undocumented] tag, you will see SE users making use of these.

Comment: "what does the ` mean" this is used to tell the context of the symbol. For global symbol, it is "Global` x" but Global is the default so no one adds it explicitly.  so GroebnerBasis`BasisAndConversionMatrix  means BasisAndConversionMatrix in context GroebnerBasis

Comment: @J.M. If there are undocumented functions, is there an unofficial list of them collected somewhere, or do you just have to look around StackExchange for what you want?

Comment: see [what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions) There is no official document to document the undocumented functions.

Comment: If you do look around SE, you'll find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/) highly-voted post in the [tag:undocumented] tag. :)